# .ipa from phonegap build wont install on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I have a Phonegap app build for iPhone and iPad. I followed below steps and was unsuccessful,

1. Downloaded `.ipa` file from `build.phonegap.com`.
2. Drag and dropped on iTunes. Clicked install and it shows **Installing**.
3. Then I pressed sync button.

But the app never opened on the device.

I am able to install on iPad but not on iPhone. It is running successfully through Xcode on iPhone and iPad.

Please guide me to install on iPhone.

Comment: check your provisioning profiles and make sure iPhone is added

Comment: is your test device and device on which ipa is not running,are same?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check below points:
1. Check UDID of the iPhone added in your provisioning profile.
2. If added, then download the provisioning profile and make build with the refreshed provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

I used the blog https://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows to generate the keys, .pem and .p12 files that are required to create a certificate.

The steps to download required certificates from developer.apple.com are followed from another blog http://www.tuladhar.net/story/first-time-use-with-ios-and-phonegap-step-by-step-guide/.

After including the generated .p12 and .mobileProvision files in build.phonegap.com, I rebuild the app and installed it on my registered iPad device. Note: in my apple account, I registered the UDID of my iPad device.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your ios certificate has not just expired. In that case you have to create a new one to enable your provisioning profile and update your phonegap build signing key.

Answer (score 0):

This was happened with me once and problem was that I had not correct development certificate and provisioning profile so I used WildCard Provision Profile and and development certificate which look like below in keychain [image: Look Like This In Keychain] and in Member Centre [image: Look Like This In Member Centre Development Certificate]. I downloaded this Development Certificate and made p12 file from it and added new key with this p12 file and my Wildcard Provisioning Profile and Thats it I solved it. I think this will be Helpful

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had a similar issue. The difference was I don't think I saw an "Installing".

What corrected it for me was simply restarting the phone. After I restarted the search still did not pick up the application until about 30 secs in. Updates seemed to work fine after this