# Unable to install ipa file builded from phonegap into iphone(Showing installing)

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ipa

I have downloaded ipa file from phonegap and tried to install in iphone through itunes but its showing installing always adn in iphone grayed color app is there below of this also showing installing is there..
I have googled about this got this link [.ipa from phonegap build wont install on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085165/ipa-from-phonegap-build-wont-install-on-iphone)  BUT didn't get suitable solution

Comment: most likely a certificate or provisioning profile issue. Make sure these are installed on the device accordingly, you can show installed ones with the `iPhone Configuration Utility` for example

Comment: @qefzec which certificate has to install in the iphone? I mean development provisional certificate or distribution provisional certificate? How to install it into iphone? Please suggest me sir, im stuck with this last two days

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed my IPA install issue from phonegap qrcode:

issue was apple de-activated our udid nbrs when our membership was renewed this year. had to re-activate on our apple account